# Build polynomial orthogonal to set of other pre-defined polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials, wavelets

Basically. the question is simple.

Is there any algorithm so I can build a polynomial, orthogonal for the set of pre-defined polynomials? I need the algorithm(like Gram-Schmidt) that would be efficient to code.

Sorry if it is too easy, but I can't figure out.

EDIT: I guess I should add more information. Here is the whole problem

Currently I'm working with multiwavelet basis(need it for solving the stochastic ODE system as described [here](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789048135196)) and can't understand how to build it. Basically, I have a set of functions $p_{i} = x^{i}$ for $i = 0,\ldots,k -1$ and a set of piecewise functions $$ f_{i} = 
\begin{cases}
p_{i}(x),  & x\ge \frac{1}{2} \\
-p_{i}(x), & x\lt \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}$$
for $i = 0,\ldots,k -1$
Now, for each $f_{i}$ i have to build $$q_{i} = f_{i} + \sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1}\alpha_{ij}p_{i}(x)$$ that $\langle q_{i},p_{i} \rangle = 0$, where 
$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$$
This operation is called "to orthogonalize $f_{i}$ with respect to set {$q_{i}(x), i = 0\ldots k - 1$}"

Basically, I don't know how to code this efficiently. I can use some kind of symbolic integration at Matlab, find all the scalar products and build a linear system of unknown $\alpha$ coefficients, but it seems completely inappropriate and inefficient for me. It is proposed in the [original paper](http://math.nist.gov/~BAlpert/l2bases.pdf) at page 249 to use Gram-Schmidt process for orthogonalizing, but as I understand this method builds new orthogonal base instead of orthogonalizing only one function with respect to others, aren't it?

Comment: Find a polynomial not in the span of your set (e.g. Of a degree higher than your set) and do Gram schmidt

Comment: How is this research? Is your predefined set infinite?

Comment: Yes, I'll have the set of orthogonal polynomials after Gram-Schmidt procedure, but they won't be orthogonal to my first set, aren't they?
Yes, in the original [paper](http://math.nist.gov/~BAlpert/l2bases.pdf) on p.249 it is proposed to use Gram-Schmidt process to orthogonalize one set of piecewise polynomials with respect to set of monomials, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I need it to build a multiwavelet basis. The pre-defined set is finite, but i need to code it for any number of elements in set

Comment: Is the problem that the number of predefined functions is much larger than the number of functions you want to orthogonalize, so orthogonalizing the predefined functions takes too long? If not, why not use Gram-Schmidt on the union of the predefined functions and the ones you want to orthogonalize? Also, why is this tagged orthogonal-groups?

Comment: My mistake with tags. Corrected.

Comment: The problem is that after Gram-Schmidt procedure I'll have completely other basis of orthogonal polynomials, aren't I?
I need to preserve the set of polynomials and just find the polynomial which is orthogonal to them

Comment: I would really suggest looking at "Interpolation & Approximation" by Philip Davis.  In addition remember that orthogonal polynomials always satisfy a simple recursion: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/2/6/126cb6a671aa1818865e6a4d7a76fc35.png